# Is it possible to create one class that can be both thread safe and non thread safe?

Tags: c#, multithreading

I have a class I want to use in different scenarios, one of which is in a single threaded env, and the other multithreaded.  I'm wondering if via generics, or some other paradigm, I can create a class which implements these two behaviors without have to create two separate classes, or pass a flag that is checked in each method.

2 Classes, 1 threadsafe, 1 nonthreadsafe. Can I elegantly combine to one?

```
public class Position
{
      public void Adjust(Trade newfill)
      {
         lock(locker)
         {
            ....
         }
      }
}

public class PositionNTS
{
      public void Adjust(Trade newfill)
      {
           ...
      }
 }
```

Comment: An uncontested lock will take maybe 20 nanoseconds. If this code isn't highly performance sensitive, then just use the code that has the lock, even in the single-threaded environment.

Comment: If you really need the difference: Create an `interface` and inject the either of the classes where they are needed. Your factory should decide what type of handling is needed here and provide the proper implementation then.

Comment: The extra cost of virtual dispatch (poor static prediction) may very well exceed the cost of entering an uncontested lock.

Answer (score 1):

Would an interface work for your?

```
public interface IPosition
{
    void Adjust(Trade newfill)
}

public class PositionNTS : IPosition
{
    public void Adjust(Trade newfill)
    {
         ...
    }
}

public class Position : IPosition
{
    private readonly object locker = new object();

    public void Adjust(Trade newfill)
    {
        lock (locker)
        {
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

You inquired about generics so this might be something you don't want to use (I'm assuming there are specific parts of your code you want to use the thread safe part and other parts you want using the non-thread safe part rather than having an easy way to swap between the two). If by environment you mean something like a production environment vs a local environment (might be fine with the non-thread safe version) you can use an IoC to flip flop between what the interface will be instantiated as. See the link for more info.
More info on an IoC: http://www.ninject.org/learn.html

Answer (score 0):

I tend agree with Jim.

But, if you still need such a class, and considering both of the classes provide identical features but  one of the class is ThreadSafe. Then why not use the following ?

Create/Use the instance as per your thread environment from where you will be using these classes.

```
public class Trade
{
}

public class PositionNTS
{
    public virtual void Adjust(Trade newfill)
    {

    }
}

public class Position : PositionNTS
{
    private readonly object locker = new object();

    public override void Adjust(Trade newfill)
    {
        lock (locker)
        {
            base.Adjust(newfill);
        }
    }
}
```

**Update**

This is another approach you can use, the decision still remains at a higher level to indicate which generic parameter is to be passed.

```
public class Trade
{

}

public interface IRunner
{
    void Adjust(Trade newfill);
}

public class Executor
{
    private IRunner runner;
    public void Adjust<T>(Trade newFill) where T : class, IRunner, new()
    {
        if(runner == null || (runner as T) == null)
        {
            runner = new T();
        }
        runner.Adjust(newFill);
    }
}

public class Runner : IRunner
{
    public void Adjust(Trade newfill)
    {
        //your logic here.
    }
}

public class SynchronizedRunner : IRunner
{
    private readonly object syncLockObject = new object();
    public void Adjust(Trade newfill)
    {
        lock (syncLockObject)
        {
            //your logic here.
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: depending on the context this might be risky (using method calls inside a lock can easily give you bad race-conditions, even worse will be events of course - but who knows, maybe Adjust will fire events later on?)

Comment: I think the questioner should be aware of this. And that's what I mentioned about the context that to use the instance as per thread environment.

Comment: I'd rather not do this since I'll have to make any changes to both classes.  I suppose the safest thing to do is leave it as it is with locking.   We have a single threades simulator and a multithreaded optimizer that share this class. The optimizer is quite slow and we found many performance issues we can fix. I was wondering if there was something that could be done with this class, but it's probably the least offensive of our issues. Thank you for help!

Comment: Another updated way, and yes, sadly there is no way a class can implicitly decide 'to use or not to use a lock'.